# Unable to connect Maxwell's Daemon to MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, change-data-capture

I'm trying to connect Maxwell's daemon to MariaDB to implement CDC. Here is the command:

`./maxwell --user='maxwell' --password='123' --host='127.0.0.1' --port=3307 --include_dbs=my_db --include_tables=my_table --producer=stdout`

At first, I got the following warning:

> 16:13:02,775 WARN  BinlogConnectorReplicator - Unhandled QueryEvent inside transaction: QueryEventData{threadId=0, executionTime=0, errorCode=0, database='', sql='# Dummy event replacing event type 160 that slave cannot handle.                                                       '}

But I was able to print messages to stdout and broadcast them via Kafka broker, so everything seemed good.

Afterward, I restarted the services and repeat the steps but this time I omitted the `--include_tables=my_table` flag and got the following error while running Maxwell's daemon:

> 16:22:49,713 ERROR TaskManager - cause: 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Unknown value type code '7B'
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.columndef.JsonColumnDef.asJSON(JsonColumnDef.java:27) ~[maxwell-1.11.0.jar:?]
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorEvent.writeData(BinlogConnectorEvent.java:104) ~[maxwell-1.11.0.jar:?]
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorEvent.buildRowMap(BinlogConnectorEvent.java:152) ~[maxwell-1.11.0.jar:?]
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorEvent.jsonMaps(BinlogConnectorEvent.java:164) ~[maxwell-1.11.0.jar:?]
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.getTransactionRows(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:182) ~[maxwell-1.11.0.jar:?]
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.getRow(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:281) ~[maxwell-1.11.0.jar:?]
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.AbstractReplicator.work(AbstractReplicator.java:148) ~[maxwell-1.11.0.jar:?]
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.util.RunLoopProcess.runLoop(RunLoopProcess.java:27) ~[maxwell-1.11.0.jar:?]
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.startInner(Maxwell.java:190) ~[maxwell-1.11.0.jar:?]
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.start(Maxwell.java:140) ~[maxwell-1.11.0.jar:?]
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.main(Maxwell.java:211) ~[maxwell-1.11.0.jar:?]
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unknown value type code '7B'
>       at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.json.JsonBinary.readValueType(JsonBinary.java:978) ~[mysql-binlog-connector-java-0.13.0.jar:0.13.0]
>       at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.json.JsonBinary.parse(JsonBinary.java:205) ~[mysql-binlog-connector-java-0.13.0.jar:0.13.0]
>       at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.json.JsonBinary.parse(JsonBinary.java:181) ~[mysql-binlog-connector-java-0.13.0.jar:0.13.0]
>       at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.json.JsonBinary.parseAsString(JsonBinary.java:168) ~[mysql-binlog-connector-java-0.13.0.jar:0.13.0]
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.columndef.JsonColumnDef.asJSON(JsonColumnDef.java:24) ~[maxwell-1.11.0.jar:?]
>       ... 10 more
>   16:22:49,715 INFO  TaskManager - Stopping: com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.PositionStoreThread@4de2ed80
>   16:22:49,715 INFO  StoppableTaskState - com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.PositionStoreThread requestStop() called (in state: RUNNING)
>   16:22:49,715 INFO  TaskManager - Stopping: com.zendesk.maxwell.producer.MaxwellKafkaProducerWorker@403e7018
>   16:22:49,715 INFO  StoppableTaskState - MaxwellKafkaProducerWorker requestStop() called (in state: RUNNING)
>   16:22:49,717 INFO  KafkaProducer - Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
>   16:22:49,718 INFO  TaskManager - Stopping: com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator@6971afb4
>   16:22:49,719 INFO  StoppableTaskState - com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator requestStop() called (in state: STOPPED)
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Unknown value type code '7B'
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.columndef.JsonColumnDef.asJSON(JsonColumnDef.java:27)
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorEvent.writeData(BinlogConnectorEvent.java:104)
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorEvent.buildRowMap(BinlogConnectorEvent.java:152)
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorEvent.jsonMaps(BinlogConnectorEvent.java:164)
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.getTransactionRows(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:182)
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.BinlogConnectorReplicator.getRow(BinlogConnectorReplicator.java:281)
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.replication.AbstractReplicator.work(AbstractReplicator.java:148)
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.util.RunLoopProcess.runLoop(RunLoopProcess.java:27)
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.startInner(Maxwell.java:190)
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.start(Maxwell.java:140)
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.Maxwell.main(Maxwell.java:211)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unknown value type code '7B'
>       at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.json.JsonBinary.readValueType(JsonBinary.java:978)
>       at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.json.JsonBinary.parse(JsonBinary.java:205)
>       at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.json.JsonBinary.parse(JsonBinary.java:181)
>       at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.event.deserialization.json.JsonBinary.parseAsString(JsonBinary.java:168)
>       at com.zendesk.maxwell.schema.columndef.JsonColumnDef.asJSON(JsonColumnDef.java:24)
>       ... 10 more
>   16:22:51,037 INFO  TaskManager - Stopped all tasks

So what's the problem?

Thanks,